# Referencing a field with a variable

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to referance a class field via variable.  like so:

```
int variable = 0;
while (variable > 3)
{
   class._fieldvariable = something;
   i++
}
```

where if I have fields: _field1, _field2, _field3 I can iterate through them all.

The main reason for doing this is I have an sql query that will append multiple records and I'd rather not have to do all the parameters multiple times but rather something like this:

```
while (i < 4)
}
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alpha1", _alphai01.ToString());
   i++
}
```

to let me set parameters 3 times with _alpha101, _alpha201 and _alpha301 are used for three different queries.

thanks!

Comment: You want an array.

Comment: If that's not possible, you will have to use reflection.

Comment: Do you have control of the class, instead of individual fields can you contain them all in an array (like SLaks suggests)?

Comment: You need to pass to PHP :-P

Comment: Or use Dictionary<string,int>, so you have the choice of reference the fields by name or looping through all of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Associate properties to the fields, all of them with get/set access.

If we're really talking about three fields, a more or less clean way to do so is by using a **function** `GetField(int index)` which would return the corresponding property. Then your code can be

```
class.GetField(i) = something;
```

An **array** is better in the more general case (for example, if the number of fields is expected to change).

I would prefer not to use reflection for such a simple purpose.

Comment: well my table is setup with 15 varchar, 10 int, 10 double, 10 bits, 5 dates.

I have an object with 3x the number of fields, and I want to split them up into different records.  alpha101 goes to the first records first varchar, alpha201 second record, first varchar, etc...

I can do a case statement to grab the correct block of parameter passes, but if i could consolidate it into one block i'd like to.

Comment: @Herrozerro What you are saying sound to me like making things more complicated than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `invokeMember` to call a certain setter of a property:

```
Object obj; //your instance;

obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Alpha1",
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
Type.DefaultBinder, obj, "ValueForAlpha1");
```

that's equal to

```
obj.Alpha1 = "ValueForAlpha1";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/66btctbe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection like this

if you have a class A

```
 public class A
    {
        int field1, field2, field3;
    }
```

you could set these fields like this

```
 A obj = new A();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(String.Format("field{0}", i), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (null != field)
            {
                field.SetValue(obj, i);
            }

        }
```